# How to access class of a java application in a network of systems?

Tags: java, class

I want to access the class and I want to use that object. Systems are connected in LAN. How can we access that system java application class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**RMI**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) or [**WebService**](http://java.sun.com/webservices/tutorial.html) to consume service of remote class/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it's quite hard to understand what you want to do...

Which class? Object? In what purpose?

You can interact with classes of another system with technologies like EJB (remote), rpc, socket, RMI, webservices, jmx...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the best way to interact with Java *.class is using RMI. Can you specify what you want to do with java code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Spring remoting:

- [Official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/remoting.html)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Remote_access_framework)
- [here on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-remoting)